# How to use Name in Ecommerce Product URL instead of parametrized ID

Tags: php, e-commerce

I am building a small ecommerce website using PHP. Right now, I am displaying data in `product.php` file using `?id=product_name` parameter. So, the current URL structure looks like:

```
mysite.com/product.php?id=boroplus-12312
```

But I want to change the URL structure to that of Amazon and Flipkart. They use product names in the URL such as:

```
flipkart.com/boroplus-antiseptic-moisturising/someOtheProductParameters
amazon.com/boroplus-antiseptic-moisturising/someOtheProductParameters
```

What I would have to change. Do I have to create folders on server or is there another way to do it? And how will I retrive the data from the database? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to create `.htaccess` file that makes all requests go to index.php, Like:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Inside **index.php** you may read request url parts like:

```
$parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
array_shift($parts);
$product_name = $parts[0];
```

**It's not best practice to build your own request handler / router**, Instead you may use a modern **PHP Framework** like Laravel, Symfony, or any MVC Framework

Comment: I want to use this template for front end=https://github.com/chekromul/uikit-ecommerce-template. I am thinking of just inserting PHP code to do the stuff dynamically. Do I really need a framework for that?

Comment: You can use any Frontend template without using any Backend framework, But you may use a framework because it helps you in building reusable components, secure your application and it's supported by a big community.